# waiting form get disappeared while executing long process

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am trying to display a waiting message, which is actually a form while a long process is running in some different file.
The issue I am facing is the form disappears once the process starts but it's still active and running the process

My code:

```
    Dim objWait As New frmWaitupdate
    Dim strReply As String

    Dim ischange As Boolean
    Dim obj1 As New MyBO.UpdateSchemaBO()
    ischange = obj1.CheckSchemaChanges(Application.ProductVersion.ToString())

    If ischange = True Then

        lblMsg.Text = "Schema changes found please wait  Please wait."

        obj1.AddVersionTable(Application.ProductVersion.ToString())
        Me.Visible = True

        strReply = obj1.UpdateSchema(Me)
        If strReply <> "" Then
            MessageBox.Show(strReply, "abc")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Schema updated successfully", "abc")
        End If


        'objWait.Hide()
    ElseIf ischange = False Then

        MessageBox.Show("No schema changes found", "abc")


        End If

    End If
```

As the process goes in UpdateSchema() which takes around 30-45 sec to finish the form disappears. Is there any way to keep the form visible on-screen until my process is finished?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the UpdateSchema call is your "long process", and that frmWaitUpdate is the form containing the message you wish to display.

Instead of calling "Me.Visible = True" you should call "objWait.Show(Me)". Make sure the wait form is not modal or else code execution will stop right there until the wait form is closed. When the long process is complete, you can call either "objWait.Hide()" or objWait.Visible = False".

Also, I believe the form in which your code is running needs to be visible before objWait.Show will work.